# jquerymobile ajax calls in blackberry 5

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have ajax calls in my wbsite that I built using jquerymobile and jquery. are these calls supposed to work on blackberry 5? what happens in this case? do the calls just go through fine except they refresh the whole page? or are they completely non functional? how do I handle this.

Comment: So I'll assume your AJAX calls aren't working on a BB5 device. You should post the code you believe does not work and explain what happens (and what you expect to happen).

Answer (score 0):

No, Ajax call probably do not work.

Correct, Ajax should safely degrade to the **B** class.

They should still be functional.  What would you like to handle?  Ajax may not be supported by the Blackberry (v 5) browser so it may not be anything you can change with code.

Checkout the official [jQuery Mobile documentation here](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/).

Comment: so I have the jquery ui autocomplete functionality that I am using which does stuff using ajax calls in jquery

Comment: so I have the jquery ui autocomplete functionality that I am using which does stuff using ajax calls in jquery. The first time the call works but from then on it doesnt until I do a page refresh. this continues.